# Username password authentication doesnt work as expected im mosquitto broker

Tags: password, authentication, username

Authentication with username and password doesnt work as expected in mosquitto broker..I am able to subscribe mosquitto_sub and publish mosquitto_pub to topics even if the username and password is wrong!! could anyone help me!!

Mosquitto.conf file includes:

`allow_anonymous false` 
`password_file path_to_the_file`
created a passwords file

Loaded the config file  `mosquitto -c path_to_the_config_file` and the config file reloads.

Reboot the system.

Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

You should add:

```
per_listener_settings true
```

at the top of your `/etc/mosquitto.conf` file, and then of course:

```
allow_anonymous false
```

to prevent anonymous connections.

Reference: http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt-username-password-example/